# How does these sleeping threads work?

Tags: java, multithreading

I am having some problems trying to figure out how the code below works. In the output I get all the threads say they are sleepy, then either Thread-1 or Thread-0 wakes up and the program freezes.

I understand that Thread-1 or Thread-0 wakes up because `threads[5]` called the `notify()` function, so the first thread in the wait-set gets back to life. But... if the thread in `threads[5]` was blocked because `wait()` was called upon it how could it still call the `wakeUp()` function?

If somehow it can call methods why doesn't the `wakeUpAll()` function work? And why it does work if I sleep the main thread?

```
public class SleepingThreads extends Thread
{
    Object lock;

    public SleepingThreads(Object l) { lock=l; }

    public void run()
    {
        System.out.println(this.getName()+" said: I am sleepy...");
        synchronized(lock)
        {
            try { lock.wait(); } catch (InterruptedException e){}
            System.out.println(this.getName()+" said: but now I woke up...");
        }
    }

   public void wakeUp() { synchronized (lock) { lock.notify(); } }

   public void wakeUpAll() { synchronized (lock) { lock.notifyAll(); } }

    public static void main(String[] args) throws InterruptedException
    {
        Object lock = new Object();
        SleepingThreads[] threads = new SleepingThreads[10];

        for (int i=0; i<10;i++)
        {
            threads[i] = new SleepingThreads(lock); 
            threads[i].start();
        }

        threads[5].wakeUp();
        //currentThread().sleep(200);
        threads[5].wakeUpAll();

        System.out.println("Done.");
    }
}
```

Comment: i think I should at least get an up vote, I was trying to tell you that the main thread was the one executing..  =)

Comment: General principle: If you have a `wait` without a while loop around it to check for a condition, you (almost) guaranteedly have a bug waiting to happen.

Comment: thanks!  I need dem points.

Comment: Your approach of adding `wakeUp` and `wakeupAll` methods to the Thread object is causing you confusion. You don't tell a specific Thread to wake up -- rather, `lock.notify()` tells *one of* the waiting Threads to wake up (which one is up to the JVM). But the way your code is written, it *seems* like you are intending to tell a specific `SleepingThreads` instance to wake up.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Two things:

1. The `wakeUp()` and `wakeUpAll()` methods are being invoked on the `threads[5]` *instance*, but not its execution *thread*. They are being invoked on the *main* thread. Thus you can call it even though the `threads[5]` *thread* is asleep.
2. The reason `main` has to sleep for 200ms is because if it doesn't, some of the threads (the ones that don't say "but now I woke up" haven't started yet, when you call `wakeUpAll()` (i.e., either they haven't executed the `run` method yet, or they haven't got to the `lock.wait()` yet). As such the `notifyAll()` occurs *before* they call `lock.wait()`, and they are never notified after waiting.

Comment: Ok so only a few of the, say they woke up because they are notified before they even went to the wait-set?

Comment: Yup, the ones that said "but now I woke up" waited before wakeUpAll() was called. The ones that do not say "but now I woke up" waited after wakeUpAll() was called. Thread execution order isn't always predictable.

Answer (score 0):

Thread 5 is not calling .wakeUp(), the main thread is calling .wakeUp()

Comment: If they all die how can the `run()` method finish? Because it does: all the threads said they woke up. Anyway this answer does not explain the behavior I observe.

Comment: why does the main thread successfully call `wakeUp()` but not `wakeUpAll()`?

Comment: See my answer, main does successfully call wakeUpAll(), and does notifyAll() on the lock, but this happens *before* some of your threads are waiting on the lock. So those threads that wait *after* the wakeUpAll() has been called never sees the notifyAll().